# Spring Data JPA, Query class with enum attributes

Tags: enums, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

```
public class RedeemCodeQuery {
private String code;
private RedeemCode.CodeStatus status;
private String exportStatus;
public static enum CodeStatus {
    INIT,USED
}

public static enum ExportStatus {
    DEFAULT,EXPORTED
}
//getter setter...
}

 String sqlByQuery = """
         select rc from RedeemCode rc 
        where (:#{#query.code} is null or rc.code = :#{#query.code} )
        and ( :status is null or rc.status = :status )
        and ( :#{#query.exportStatus} is null or rc.exportStatus = :#{#query.exportStatus} )
        """;
@Query(sqlByQuery)
Page<RedeemCode> pageBy(@Param("query") RedeemCodeQuery query, @Param("status") CodeStatus status, Pageable pageable);
```

rc.code = :#{#query.code}:  working , code is type of String and inside the RedeemCodeQuery class;

rc.status = :status : working, status is type of enum.

rc.exportStatus = :#{#query.exportStatus}: error , exportStatus is type of enum and inside the RedeemCodeQuery class.

Spring SpEL may change the :#{#query.exportStatus} to some other type. Is possible to put an enum inside a class for query parameter? How to do that?

Comment: I'm curious which one have you chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. either use `Enum.name()` to get the `String` representation of `rc.exportStatus` field for comparison with `String` `rc.exportStatus` parameter:

```java
String sqlByQuery = """
         select rc from RedeemCode rc 
        where (:#{#query.code} is null or rc.code = :#{#query.code} )
        and ( :status is null or rc.status = :status )
        and ( :#{#query.exportStatus} is null or rc.exportStatus.name() = :#{#query.exportStatus} )
        """;
@Query(sqlByQuery)
Page<RedeemCode> pageBy(@Param("query") RedeemCodeQuery query, @Param("status") CodeStatus status, Pageable pageable);
```

2. or use special `T()` [operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/types.html) with `Enum.valueOf()` for conversion of `String` `rc.exportStatus` field into member of `ExportStatus` enum:

```java
String sqlByQuery = """
         select rc from RedeemCode rc 
        where (:#{#query.code} is null or rc.code = :#{#query.code} )
        and ( :status is null or rc.status = :status )
        and ( :#{#query.exportStatus} is null or rc.exportStatus = :#{T(full.path.to.ExportStatus).valueOf(#query.exportStatus)})
        """;
@Query(sqlByQuery)
Page<RedeemCode> pageBy(@Param("query") RedeemCodeQuery query, @Param("status") CodeStatus status, Pageable pageable);
```

3. or use the dirty hack: SpEL expression `#query.exportStatus` assumes there's a getter for `exportStatus` field, so you could modify it to return  `ExportStatus` instead of `String` keeping your initial query:

```java
public class RedeemCodeQuery {
private String code;
private RedeemCode.CodeStatus status;
private String exportStatus;

public static enum ExportStatus {
    DEFAULT,EXPORTED
}

public ExportStatus getExportStatus() {
  return ExportStatus.valueOf(exportStatus);
}
```

This would give you desirable type at runtime.